# Counterexample: Functions and Difference of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out a counterexample for this proposition
Let $f:X \to   Y$ be a function, $A\subset X$. Then
$$f(X-A) \subset Y -f(A).$$ and
$$Y-f(A) \subset f(X-A).$$
I don’t have any idea; I tried with simple functions but none worked.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  What about $ f(x)=x^2$, $X=\mathbb R$, $A=\{x \in \mathbb R | x > 0\}$?

Comment: Wow, it was so simple, thank you very much :) . How can I give you stars? How can I confirm that this answer has a question?

Comment: Ok, I entered an official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of proof sketches that will indicate what you need for counterexamples.

If y in Y - f(A), then y not in f(A);
for all x in A, y /= f(x).
If exists x in X with y = f(x), then show y in f(X - A).

If y in f(X - A), then exists x in X - A with y = f(x).
Show if f is injective, that y not in f(A), y in Y - f(x).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample for the proposition.     Let $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and $A=(0,\infty)$ and$ f(x)=x^2.$

Then $f(A)=(0,\infty), X-A=(-\infty,0],$ and

$f(X-A) = [0,\infty) \not \subset  Y-f(A) = \mathbb R - (0,\infty)=(-\infty,0].$

Also in this example, $Y-f(A)=(-\infty,0] \not \subset f(X-A)=[0,\infty).$